# installation of Google Earth Engine API in conda fails

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to install Google Earth Engine API for Python, but am running into some problems. I am following the directions [here](https://github.com/earthlab/tutorials/blob/master/documentation/intro-google-earth-engine-python-api.md). Within a conda environment, I can verify everything until step 6. When I enter `python -c "import ee; ee.Initialize()"` at the command line, I receive the error "No module named ee". However, `conda list` shows that ee has been installed via Pip.

Has anyone else had this problem?

I have had ee successfully configured, but had to unfortunately delete everything because of ArcGIS Pro and so I am having trouble reinitializing ee.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that when you clone an environment with Anaconda within ArcGIS Pro, the cloned environment still links back to the old python executable. However, if you are in a cloned environment and start an IDE (e.g. Spyder), python links to the python executable in the cloned environment. This is not consistent, but appears to be the way it is.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using the conda package manager, you can install the [earthengine-api conda package from the conda-forge channel](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/earthengine-api) instead of using pip.

```
conda install -c conda-forge earthengine-api
```

This approach has the advantage of taking care of the cryptography dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since you previously had ee successfully configured, not sure that this applies, but it looks like that if your account isn't whitelisted to use Earth Engine you will have an issue with step 6. From earthengine-API on Github: [Unable to initialize the GEE python client while processing "ee.Initialize()"](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/issues/27)

Comment: The problem is a step before ee.Initialize(). I am unable to import ee into python, even though it is listed as an installed package.

Comment: Do you receive "ee.ee_exception.EEException: Server returned HTTP code: 404"? I had the same problem when I just installed and it is bc my acct isn't whitelisted

Comment: No, I was receiving the message  "No module named ee". The problem is that I am using Anaconda within ArcPro 2.0. When I created a clone of the ArcGIS environment so that I could install packages, the link to the old python executable was used. Pip is looking in the old environment. When I provide the full path to the cloned python executable, it works. Now I just have to figure out how to set the cloned path to the python executable.

Comment: I think that this is more of an ArcPro question, so I am going to request this question be removed and I start another question centered around ArcPro and Conda

Answer (score 0):

PolyGeo appears to be right here, something is calling back to the proenv environment in a cloned environment. in my traceback I would see a callback to

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\runpy.py

despite running in an activated conda environment.

The only way I could get past this issue was to run in admin, activate propenv and install a copy of earthengine-api directly into the pro environment which I really don't like doing.